# OTRS Dashboard not showing queue data for certain agent / role combinations

Tags: otrs

In my OTRS implementation I am using roles to set permissions for agents.  In this case I have two levels of access.  One set of Agents get full access (with permission "rw" checked) of group X via role Y.  Another set of agents have only "ro", "note", "owner", "priority" checked for group X via role Z.

When accessing the dashboard, users who are assigned role Y have access to the tickets in the various dashboard sections.  Users assigned role Z do not have access to any ticket information within the dashboard.

When debugging what I found was a user had to have the "rw" permission set for the group in the role for it to work.  Anything else did not work.

What is the proper way this should work?  Or am I mising something?  If feel the dashboard should work with simply having access to the group.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, OTRS only lists RW, but you can change that:

```
?Action=AdminSysConfig;Subaction=Edit;SysConfigSubGroup=Frontend::Agent::Dashboard;SysConfigGroup=Ticket;#
```